# Xamarin WatchOS Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _GetProductInfo

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-watch, watchos

I try to build and deploy my Xamarin WatchOS App on a real Apple Watch Gen.5 and get these three errors.

```
Native linking failed undefined symbol: _GetProductInfo. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
```

What I figured out so far:

I use the Microsoft Azure Devices Client Package version 1.26 in my App, when I delete any reference to this package, the app builds just fine and I can run the app on my Watch, I think somewhere here is the problem. But in the Simulator my App runs with reference to this Azure package just fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Environment:

- macOS 15.4
- Visual Studio for Mac 8.6.3
- Xcode 11.5

Comment: What is your linking configuration set to?

Comment: Linker behavior is set to "Link All"

Comment: Can you try just for the test to `Link SDK only`?

Comment: I tried this, but still get an error for release version. My Debug version is up and running with link all and architecture option set to ARM64_32. Off-topic: Now I run into another issue with the same Azure package: "System.Net.Dns:GetHostByName is not supported on this platform" when trying to connect to Azure. Does someone know a good tutorial or example, how to get started with a network connection on Apple WatchOS using Xamarin? I just found nothing related to this

Comment: Did you ever solve this ?